# How to fix permission error in writing to file internal memory android?

Tags: java, android

I need to write a function which is responsible write a string into a file (inside internal memory i.e /internalMem/DCIM).

I have added permission in my Androidmanifest.xml file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Here is the function I have

```
  public void save(View v, String text)  {
        if (checkSelfPermission(android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            Log.v(TAG, "Permission is not granted!");

        }
         
        final File path = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory
                            ( Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM );
                                    //Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES

        if (!path.exists()) {
           path.mkdirs();
        }

        final File file = new File(path, "testing.txt");
        if (!file.exists()) {
            Log.e("cannot create the test.txt file: ", "File write failed: ");
        }

        try {
           file.createNewFile();
           FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(file);
           OutputStreamWriter myOutWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(fOut);
           myOutWriter.append(text);

           myOutWriter.close();

           fOut.flush();
           fOut.close();
       } catch (IOException e) {
           Log.e("Exception", "File write failed: " + e.toString());
       }
  }
```

But i observe it catches the debugging message "permission is not granted", and also get the following error

```
E/cannot create the test.txt file:: File write failed:
E/Exception: File write failed: java.io.IOException: Operation not permitted
```

Any suggestion how to fix?

Answer (score 0):

You have to ask the user to grant [permission](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting)

You should also know saving files there isnt as simple as setting the path, please read the docs about [storage](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage)